# How to get AutoCAD Civil3D drawing extents from API like Civil3D does?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad, autocad-plugin, autodesk-designautomation

I want to extract drawing extents from Civil3D dwg's using Design Automation.

If I use the code below:

```
static public Extents3d GetExtents(Database db) {
  try {
    //db.UpdateExt(true);

    return new Extents3d(db.Extmin, db.Extmax);
  } catch {
    return new Extents3d();
  }
}
```

Then I get the following result which is correct:

```
Min: [2538909.32, 330601.59, 0.00]
Max: [2540326.77, 331107.96, 0.00]
```

However, if I call `db.UpdateExt(true)` before or if I simply iterate all entities in model space with the code below, I get a min bound that is at origin:

```
static public Extents3d GetExtents(Database db) {
  try {
    var TxMng = db.TransactionManager;

    using(var Tx = TxMng.StartTransaction()) {
      var btr = Tx.GetObject(
        db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForRead)
      as BlockTableRecord;

      foreach(var id in btr) {
        var entity = Tx.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead)
        as Entity;

        extents.AddExtents(entity.GeometricExtents);
      }

      Tx.Commit();
    }

    return extents;
  } catch {
    return new Extents3d();
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Min: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
Max: [2540326.77, 331107.96, 0.00]
```

Also opening the dwg in AutoCAD vanilla and doing a zoom extents will use this huge/invalid extents. So I think Civil knows that some entities should not be included when computing extents or is it something else?

I would like to be able to compute extents using the second approach (at least a modified working version of it) as it offers more granularity over what entities we want to consider if later on we have some more advanced requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating the entities to compute the extends, it is OK we do not include the entity AeccDbNetworkPartConnector. You can use the API `entity.GetRXClass().Name` to get the name `AeccDbNetworkPartConnector`, which can help filter out these entities.